# Explicitly set dummy variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have data that looks like:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Bob', 'Dan', 'Jack'], 
        'Color1':['red', 'red', 'black', 'blue'],
        'Color2':['blue', 'green', 'green', 'white'],
        'Color3':['orange', 'purple', 'white', 'red'],
        'Color4':['', 'yellow', 'purple', '']
} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to set dummy variables for each person, so that if a specific color is listed for a person in any of `color1, color2, color3, color4`, then that person receives a `1`, or else that person receives a `0`. However, I'm not interested in setting a dummy variable for every color that appears: I'm only interested in setting variables for colors red, black, and yellow.

Thus the expected output would be:

```
result = {'Name':['Tom', 'Bob', 'Dan', 'Jack'], 
        'hasRed':[1, 1, 0, 1],
        'hasBlack':[0, 0, 1, 0],
        'hasYellow':[0, 0, 1, 0]
} 
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

I know pandas has a `get_dummy` function, but I don't think it can be used on multiple columns for specific variables like I need in my case. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Let us try melting the dataframe, filter the colors and crosstab:

```
colors = ['red','blue','yellow']

tmp = (df.melt('Name')
    .loc[lambda x: x['value'].isin(colors)]
)

pd.crosstab(tmp['Name'],tmp['value']).add_prefix('has_').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
value  Name  has_blue  has_red  has_yellow
0       Bob         0        1           1
1      Jack         1        1           0
2       Tom         1        1           0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `stack` + `get_dummies`

```
out = df.set_index('Name').stack().loc[lambda x : x.isin(['red','blue','yellow'])].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
Out[404]: 
      blue  red  yellow
Name                   
Tom      1    1       0
Bob      0    1       1
Jack     1    1       0
```

Or

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df,prefix = 'has',prefix_sep='_',columns=df.columns[1:])[['Name','has_blue' , 'has_red' , 'has_yellow']].sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[409]: 
   Name  has_blue  has_red  has_yellow
0   Tom         1        1           0
1   Bob         0        1           1
2   Dan         0        0           0
3  Jack         1        1           0
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try `pd.get_dummies` with max on `axis=1`

```
out = df[['Name']].join(pd.get_dummies(df.drop("Name",1),prefix='',prefix_sep='')
            .max(level=0,axis=1)
            .loc[:,['red','black','yellow']].add_prefix("has"))
```

---

```
print(out)

   Name  hasred  hasblack  hasyellow
0   Tom       1         0          0
1   Bob       1         0          1
2   Dan       0         1          0
3  Jack       1         0          0
```